How to use SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getChanges method?
I'm trying to use this method in google apps script in the function that is triggered with OnChange event.
function sendResultsEmail(e) {
  const content = e.source.getChanges.toString();
  console.log(content);
}

This prits out function () { [native code] }
But when I use it this way e.source.getChanges(), I get an error
Exception: The parameters () don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getChanges.
    at sendResultsEmail(TriggerCreation:13:40)

The thing is, there is no documentation for this method anywhere. And yet, e.source.toString() shows that it exists.
Trigger creation:
function setupTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendResultsEmail')
    .forSpreadsheet('REDACTED')
    .onChange()
    .create();
}

I don't even know if it's useful to my cause. What am I doing wrong?

Use the "Change" event object to discover what changes caused the "on change" trigger to fire. You can access past revisions through the Drive API using the Revisions resource. See Download and publish file revisions and How to get older versions of Google Spreadsheet data for sample code.

Is this an XY problem?

There is no getChanges method for Class Spreadsheet

Sending a bunch of different types to test it...
function testGetChanges(){
  const s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  [1, "1", new Date()].forEach((o) => {
    try {
      console.log(s.getChanges(o))
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  })
}

The logs showed:
{ [Exception: The parameters (number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getChanges.] name: 'Exception' }
{ [Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getChanges.] name: 'Exception' }
{ [Exception: The api method 'getChanges' is not available yet in the new version of Google Sheets.] name: 'Exception' }

Apparently,  The parameter type is date and it was probably used to get changes in a spreadsheet from a given date.
Unfortunately, As the error says,

The api method 'getChanges' is not available yet in the new version of Google Sheets.

This seems like a legacy feature used in old Google sheets and wouldn't help anyone today.

If what you want is to know what changes were made to the spreadsheet...
function sendResultsEmail(e) {
  const content = e.changeType;
  console.log(content);
}

